# Java doPost() works when using getParameter(),but doGet() always throws null... WHY?

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I have a servlet with **doGet()** and **doPost()** functions. When i use **getParameter()** on **doPost()** it works perfect, but when i use **getParameter()** inside **doGet()** it can't get the parameters... it says they're null. These are my codes.

**HTML (index.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>JAVA-AJAX Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxfunctions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Enviar POST mediante AJAX</h1>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="Puma" />
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="Bernal" />
    <input type="button" id="sendpost" name="sendpost" value="Send POST" />
    <hr/>
    <h1>Enviar GET mediante AJAX</h1>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="Jose" />
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="Bernal" />
    <input type="button" id="sendget" name="sendget" value="Send GET" />
</body>
```

**JavaScript (ajaxfunctions.js):**

```
window.onload = function()
{
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //*************************************POST FUNCTIONS************************************************

    var sendpost = document.getElementById("sendpost");

    sendpost.onclick = function()
    {
        var username = document.getElementById("username");
        var password = document.getElementById("password");

        if (username.value == "" || password.value == "")
            alert("Debe ingresar el usuario y la contraseña!");
        else
            enviarDatosPost(username, password);
    }

    function enviarDatosPost(username, password)
    {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = prepararRespuestaPost;
        xhr.open("POST", "Messages", true);
        var datosPost = crearDatosPost(username, password);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        alert("POST: " + datosPost);
        xhr.send(datosPost);
    }

    function crearDatosPost(username, password)
    {
        var datosPost = "username="+username.value+"&password="+password.value;
        return datosPost;
    }

    function prepararRespuestaPost()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            if (xhr.status == 200)
            {
                alert("XHR responseText: " + xhr.responseText + "\nXHR statusText: " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        }
    }

    //*************************************GET FUNCTIONS************************************************

    var sendget = document.getElementById("sendget");

    sendget.onclick = function()
    {
        var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
        var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname");

        if (firstname.value == "" || lastname.value == "")
            alert("Debe ingresar el nombre y el apellido!");
        else
            enviarDatosGet(firstname, lastname);
    }

    function enviarDatosGet(firstname, lastname)
    {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = prepararRespuestaGet;
        xhr.open("GET", "Messages", true);
        var datosGet = crearDatosGet(firstname, lastname);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        alert("GET: " + datosGet);
        xhr.send(datosGet);
    }

    function crearDatosGet(firstname, lastname)
    {
        var datosGet = "firstname="+firstname.value+"&lastname="+lastname.value;
        return datosGet;
    }

    function prepararRespuestaGet()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            if (xhr.status == 200)
            {
                alert("XHR responseText: " + xhr.responseText + "\nXHR statusText: " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Java (Messages.java):**

```
package com.puma.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.*;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class Messages
 */
@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true, urlPatterns = { "/Messages" })
public class Messages extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Messages()
    {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String responseData = "";
        String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname"); 
        System.out.println("DATOS - First Name: " + firstname + " / Last name: " + lastname);
        if (firstname.equals("Jose") && lastname.equals("Bernal"))
            responseData = "USUARIO CONOCIDO - Name : " + firstname + " / Last name: " + lastname;
        else
            responseData = "USUARIO DESCONOCIDO - Name: " + firstname + " / Last name: " + lastname;

        System.out.println(responseData);

        OutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        writer.write(responseData);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String responseData = "";
        String user = request.getParameter("username");
        String pass = request.getParameter("password");
        if (user.equals("Puma") && pass.equals("Bernal"))
            responseData = "DATOS CORRECTOS - Username : " + user + " / Password: " + pass;
        else
            responseData = "DATOS INCORRECTOS - Username: " + user + " / Password: " + pass;

        System.out.println(responseData);

        OutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        writer.write(responseData);
        writer.flush();
    }
}
```

If you look, POST and GET are structured exactly the same way. POST works perfectly but GET don't. Am i doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST does work by sending parameters in the body of the request. GET works with parameters encoded in the URL. So for the GET part, you need to append the variables to the URL like this: myurl?paramname=paramvalue&paramname2=paramvalue3

And don't forget to encode the parameters before appending them to the URL.

Comment: Don't forget you can accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'm new to stackoverflow, but i think that did it!